# Trigger added methods of derived class by method in base class

Tags: c++, testing, inheritance, virtual-functions

I want to implement a simple test structure. Here is how I created base class and derived class.

*testBase.h:*

```
class TestBase {
public:
    TestBase() {}
    virtual void TestStart() = 0;
    virtual void TestEnd() = 0;
    void RunTest() {  
        // I need code here to trigger a chain of calls
    }
};
```

*classifierTest.h:*

```
#include "testBase.h"

class ClassifierTest: public TestBase
{
public:
    ClassifierTest() {
    
    }
    void TestStart();
    void TestEnd();

    void Test1();
    void Test2();
    void Test3();
};
```

*classifierTest.cpp:*

```
#include "classifierTest.h"

void ClassifierTest::TestStart() {

}

void ClassifierTest::TestEnd() {

}

void ClassifierTest::Test1(){

}

void ClassifierTest::Test2(){

}

void ClassifierTest::Test3(){

}
```

*main function:*

```
ClassifierTest *classifierTest = new ClassifierTest();
classifierTest->RunTest();
```

Suppose `Test1()`, `Test2()` and `Test3()` are my test methods, and **I may add more tests here in future**.
My goal is that when I call `RunTest()` in the main function, then these test methods are called one by one, after `TestStart()`, and before `TestEnd()`.

so they would run like:

- `TestStart()`
- `Test1()`
- `TestEnd()`
- `TestStart()`
- `Test2()`
- `TestEnd()`
- `TestStart()`
- `Test3()`
- `TestEnd()`

I don't want to specifically add test method in the base class. But the question is how to trigger these chain of calls from RunTest(). So the base trigger methods that it doesn't know about them.

I believe it should be sth like reflection in .net?

Comment: Do you have a question about this?  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: btw it can be fun to play around with creating your own testing framework, but soon you will find out that you are reinventing a wheel. There are plenty good existing solutions

Comment: I want to be as minimalist as possible with test code. I may start using one if this doesn't work. Any suggestion for a light one?

Comment: @AryanFirouzian a light one _what_?  Testing library?

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, I was referring to test library. Sth simple that does what I am trying to do here.

Comment: There are two well-known libs, one from Google (gtest, I believe) and one from Boost. In any case, automatic discovery of test functions requires reflection, which is not in C++. You could perhaps register the functions in the baseclass, provided they all have the same signature. Just store function pointers in a container. Or, take another step and register `std::function` objects there. Those and lambdas could even eliminate the requirement for a derived class completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking for reflection which isnt present in C++ (yet). Now the quesiton is what comprosmise you are willing to make.

If you are fine with writing some code to manually register the test functions, then they don't need to be members and a possible solution is this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class TestBase {
public:
    TestBase() {}
    virtual void TestStart() = 0;
    virtual void TestEnd() = 0;
    
    void RunTest() {  
        for (const auto& test_fun : test_functions){
            TestStart();
            test_fun();
            TestEnd();
        }
    }
    using test_function = std::function<void()>;
    void register_test(const test_function& fun){ test_functions.push_back(fun); }
private:
    
    std::vector<test_function> test_functions;
};

class ClassifierTest: public TestBase
{
public:
    ClassifierTest() {
        register_test([](){ std::cout << "test 1\n";});
        register_test([](){ std::cout << "test 2\n";});
    }
    void TestStart() { std::cout << "test start\n";}
    void TestEnd() { std::cout << "test end\n";}
};

int main() {
    ClassifierTest{}.RunTest();
}
```

[Output:](https://godbolt.org/z/jcPWE5595)

```
test start
test 1
test end
test start
test 2
test end
```

Note that if you capture `this` the lambdas can use members, so there isnt much difference to your initial approach and the amount of code to write is also comparable:

```
class ClassifierTest2: public TestBase
{
public:
    ClassifierTest2() {
        register_test([this](){ std::cout << "test 1, x = " << x << "\n";});
        register_test([this](){ std::cout << "test 2, x = " << x << "\n";});
    }
    void TestStart() { ++x;std::cout << "test start\n";}
    void TestEnd() { std::cout << "test end\n";}
private:
    int x = 0;
};

int main() {
    ClassifierTest2{}.RunTest();
}
```

[Output:](https://godbolt.org/z/3E1Ydx3rs)

```
test start
test 1, x = 1
test end
test start
test 2, x = 2
test end
```

As mentioned already in a comment, if you manually register `TestStart` and `TestEnd` as well, then there is no need for the derived classes. It could be just a class `Test` with `register_test_start(std::function<void()>)` and `register_test_end(std::function<void()>)` or pass them as parameters to the constructor.